# bootstrap rows not folding properly on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to make rows of images. On phone screens, there should be 2 images per row. On every screen size larger than phones, there should be 3 images per row.  The code below works for screens larger than a phone, but on a phone it leaves a blank space after the 3rd image.  How do I make it so on mobile there are no missing spaces?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason to have two rows? If not, this is the solution.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want raw [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) rather than rows and columns. Use flex-basis on a custom class to handle wrapping.

Since "larger than phones" isn't particularly specific I went with the medium breakpoint (768px) to correspond with [Bootstrap's native breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). You may prefer 992px or even 1200px.

Protip: Bootstrap already has [a class for image max-width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/images/#responsive-images) (and you shouldn't use inline styles anyway--create custom classes where needed).

```css
.img-box {
  flex-basis: calc(100%/2);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .img-box {
    flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/ccaaaa" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/ccaaaa" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/ccaaaa" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```